# Spring Junit Database Connection Lost

Tags: java, spring, junit4

Running multiple test classes in junit with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is causing "Could not connect to underlying database." In @Before annotation i am mocking all beans and using it in test methods.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.apache.logging.log4j.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.crypto.*",
    "javax.management.*" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:services.xml", "classpath:persistence.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@PrepareForTest({ CommonsUtil.class })
@Transactional
```

public class CustomerTest {

```
// I have loaded all beans required to run this test…. But leading to db connection lost If I run multiple classes like this
@Autowired
CommonService commonSvc;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("registrationService")
RegistrationService registrationSvc;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("paymentProcessor")
PaymentProcessor paymentProcesser;

@Autowired
InquiryCustTxnHandler inquiryCustTxnHandler;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.spy(CommonsUtil.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn(CommonUtilMock.getApplicationContext()).when(CommonsUtil.class, "getApplicationContext");
    OvoIntegrationProxy ovoIntegrationProxy = Mockito.mock(OvoIntegrationProxy.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ovoIntegrationProxy, "ovoHost", "http://localhost:8080/");
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(commonSvc, "ovoIntegrationProxy", ovoIntegrationProxy);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(registrationSvc, "commonService", commonSvc);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(paymentProcesser, "registrationService", registrationSvc);
}

@Test
public void inquiryCustomer() throws Exception {
    InquiryCustRequestHelper hlpr = new InquiryCustRequestHelper();
    InquiryCustResp resp = null;
    String xml = hlpr.formInquiryCustRegXml(custreg.getEMoneyId());
    SubmitTransaction transactionRequest = new SubmitTransaction();
    transactionRequest.setRequestXml(xml);
    try {
         BaseTransferObject result = inquiryCustTxnHandler.handleTransaction(transactionRequest);
         resp = hlpr.getUnMarshalled(result.getSpringResponseXml());                        
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Which layer you are testing?

Comment: @Dhivya Does your datasource have any limitations on the number of open connections?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ikaaz_new_dev2?autoReconnect=true" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="root" />
  <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
  <property name="minIdle" value="3" />
 </bean>

Comment: I wanted to do code coverage so i have to test all controller service and dao's